# Can you give me an example of array name as lvalue?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

```
    int a[3]={1,2,3};
    printf("%p\n", &a);
```

Array name is pointer constant. So that makes me think it is rvalue.
The & operator requires a lvalue.
The code above has no warnings or errors.
Can you give me an example of array name as lvalue?

Comment: [Is there a reason why an array name is not an lvalue?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39023316). tldr; _"An array can be an lvalue (but not a modifiable lvalue), and an "array name" (identifier) is always an lvalue."_

Comment: *Array name is pointer constant.*  That's an often-repeated but misleading, not really correct, and not very useful statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of thinking about the terms "lvalue" and "rvalue".

An lvalue is something that can occur on the left-hand side of an assignment operator.
An rvalue is something that can occur on the right-hand side of an assignment operator.

Or, the other way of thinking about is that an lvalue is something that has a location.  An rvalue is just a value.

You can turn an lvalue into an rvalue by fetching the value at the location.

So if we say

```
int i, j;
i = 3;
```

Then in `i = 3`, `i` is an lvalue and `3` is an rvalue.

If we then say

```
j = i;
```

`j` is an lvalue.  `i` starts out being an lvalue, but in the process of evaluating the expression, we turn it into an rvalue, by fetching its value.

What if we say

```
3 = j;             /* WRONG */
```

But 3 is an rvalue, not an lvalue.  3 is just a value, it doesn't have a location.  So there's no way we can "store something in 3".

That's why we must have an lvalue on the left-hand side of an assignment operator: so that we have a location in which to store the value.

Now, arrays.  Arrays are special in C.  An array name is an lvalue (because it has a location).  But when an array name appears in a context where we need its value -- where we're about to turn the lvalue into an rvalue -- what happens next is *not* the same as for an ordinary variable.

For an ordinary variable like `i`, when we turn it into an rvalue, we fetch its value.
But for an array, when we turn it into an rvalue, something very different happens: the value we derive is a *pointer to the array's first element*.  This pointer is an rvalue, but it's a pointer rvalue, not an array rvalue.  In C, *there are no rvalues of array type*.

If we say

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int *ip;
ip = a;
```

then in `ip = a`, `a` starts out as an array lvalue, but then turns into a pointer rvalue, which gets assigned to `ip`.

If we then say

```
int b[10];
b = a;             /* WRONG */
```

then `b` is an array lvalue.  But arrays are not assignable in C.  (Another way of saying this is that an array name is not a *modifiable lvalue*.)

I'm not sure why you're looking for an "example of array name as lvalue".  It's sort of like looking for a purple cow -- you're not likely to find one.

---

In a comment you asked,

> the system allocates memory for the array elements, and the pointer `p`, but does not allocate memory for the identifier `a`. Is that right?

No, not quite.  The memory allocated for the array elements *is* the memory allocated for the identifier `a`.  I usually think of the situation with little labeled boxes, like this:

```
    +-----+
 i: |  3  |
    +-----+

    +-----+
 j: |  3  |
    +-----+

    +-----+-----+-----+
 a: |  1  |  2  |  3  |
    +-----+-----+-----+
       ^
       |
    +--|--+
ip: |  *  |
    +-----+

    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 b: |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

The identifiers themselves don't take up any memory.  (I didn't draw them in boxes.)  An identifier is just a permanent association between a name (like `a` or `ip`) and a location, the location of some memory the compiler allocated for you to hold one of your variables.

So you could say that every identifier is an lvalue, although not every lvalue has an identifier.

Comment: The C standard makes a distinction between an *lvalue* and a *modifiable lvalue*.  An array is an lvalue, but is not a modifiable lvalue.   From the standard:  A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const- qualified type.

Comment: `int a[3]={1,2,3 }; int *p=a; `  the system allocates memory for the array elements, and the pointer p, but does not allocate memory for the identifier a. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

> Array name is pointer constant.

This is incorrect.

`a` is not a pointer, `const` or otherwise.  The *expression* `a` has type "3-element array of `int`."  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted, or "decays", to an expression of type "pointer to `int`" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.